# Get counts of one numpy array using another array as what to count based on

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following code using bincounts to get occurrences

```
print(categories = df[attribute].cat.categories)
>>> Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')
print(df[attribute].to_numpy())
>>> [0 1 0 1 1]
partition = np.bincount(df[attribute].to_numpy())
print(partition)
>>> [2 3]
```

What I want is so that it is counting but using bins based on the categories array such that it would be `[2 3 0]` because there are no 2's in the array. Is there any way to do this? My dataframes are always setup such that categorical data types are integer encoded starting from 0 up to the number of classes. I want to avoid using `df[attribute].value_count()` because profiling makes it seem like it is a bottleneck, though I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Your values are 0, 1, 2 and you use `CategoricaDtype`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `return_counts=True`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'attribute': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]})
df = df.astype({'attribute': pd.CategoricalDtype([0, 1, 2])})

cat, count = np.unique(df['attribute'], return_counts=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> cat, count
(array([0, 1]), array([2, 3]))
```

Suggested by @jezrael, to get your expected output, you can use:

```
>>> pd.Series(count, index=cat).reindex(df['attribute'].cat.categories, fill_value=0)
0    2
1    3
2    0
dtype: int64
```

But you have to compare the performance with:

```
>>> df['attribute'].value_counts(sort=False)
0    2
1    3
2    0
Name: attribute, dtype: int64
```

Comment: OP need `print (pd.Series(count, index=cat).reindex(df['attribute'].cat.categories, fill_value=0))`

Comment: In this case, I think `df['attribute'].value_counts(sort=False)` is better than recreate a Series from scratch, no?

Comment: OP dont want `value_counts` - `I want to avoid using df[attribute].value_count()`

Comment: If it is faster hard to know, because depends of no of values and number of rows.

Comment: We don't know if `value_counts` has been thoroughly compared. Depends on data and algorihtms: sorting or just hash-based grouping. But I maintain that going from pandas to numpy looks a bit awkward.

Answer (score 0):

If input is already a pandas dataframe/series, you can use [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) in place of bare-metal numpy's operations. Here is a fully working example

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([0,1,0,1,1], dtype="category", name='attribute')
df = pd.DataFrame(s)
df.value_counts('attribute')
```

Giving the output

```
attribute
1    3
0    2
dtype: int64
```